# Imaginary part of $\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I want to prove that:

$$ \Im\left(\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}\right) = 0 \qquad \textit{iff} \qquad \Im(z) = 0$$

I tried to plot the function on mathematica and it seems true, excluding the poles on the negative real axis.
Thanks

Comment: What do you get from $\frac{\pi \cos(\pi s)}{\sin(\pi s)} = \frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s)-\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(1-s)$ at least for $\Re(s) \in \mathbb{Z}/2$

Comment: $$
\Im\left(\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}\right) = \Im\left(\frac{\Gamma(z)\psi^{(0)}\left(z\right)}{\Gamma(z)}\right) = \Im\left(\psi^{(0)}\left(z\right)\right) = 0
$$

Comment: Why is that? I mean $\psi^{(0)}$ is just another definition of $\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ so I can not see why what you wrote is true

Comment: The (unique) analytic continuation of $\Gamma(z)$ from positive reals to the complex plane minus the poles obeys $z \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z + 1)$, therefore $\Gamma(z)$ is real-valued on the real axis (minus the poles). The derivative can be taken along the real axis, therefore $\Gamma'(z)$ is also real-valued.

Comment: Yes that is true, but one has to exclude the case where, for example, $\Gamma(z)=\Gamma'(z)$ which can happen also in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\psi(z) = -\gamma -
 \sum_{k \geq 1} \left( \frac 1 {k + z - 1} - \frac 1 k \right), \\
\operatorname{Im} \frac 1 {k + z - 1} =
-\frac {\operatorname{Im} z}
 {(\operatorname{Re} z + k - 1)^2 + \operatorname{Im}^2 z},$$
therefore $\operatorname{sgn} \operatorname{Im} \psi(z) = \operatorname{sgn} \operatorname{Im} z$.

Comment: agree: your answer is more exhaustive (+1)

Answer (score 0):

By definition of derivative of a complex function
$$
f'(z) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta \,z\; \to \;0}  = {{f(z + \Delta z) - f(z)} \over {\Delta z}}
$$
the limit must exist and be the same for whichever
$$
\Delta z = \left| {\Delta z} \right|e^{\,i\,\arg \left( {\Delta z} \right)} 
$$
i.e. for whichever value of its argument, i.e. whichever direction in the complex plane.

So if $f(z)$ is analytic in $z=r \in \mathbb R$ and $f(r) \in \mathbb R$ then its derivative exist and is equal
to the derivative in $r$, and viceversa the derivative in $r$ is equal to the derivative in $z$ (at $z=r$).
And Gamma respects such conditions.

Comment: Note though that there is an "iff" in the question.

Comment: @Maxim: well yes, the implication is bi-directional ; however I put it explicitely.

Comment: But now the task is to prove that $\operatorname{Im} \psi(z) = 0 \supset \operatorname{Im} z = 0$.

Comment: @maxim: do you mean that it is also to prove that $\psi(z)$ is real only on the real axis ?

Comment: Correct. If it says "iff", surely it means equivalence.